# pandas Two DataFrames with multipindex, add together?

Tags: pandas

We Know that dataframe can add anther dataframe by index.
While i has two dataframes with multipindex, so how can i add them by level 'a' in index.

```
data3.head()
        c   d   e
a  b
0  1    2   3   4
5  6    7   8   9
10 11  12  13  14
15 16  17  18  19
20 21  22  23  24
data4.head()
        b   d   e
a  c             
0  2    1   3   4
5  7    6   8   9
10 12  11  13  14
15 17  16  18  19
20 22  21  23  24
25 27  26  28  29
data3 + data4
error:merging with both multi-indexes is not implemented
```

Comment: May be i'm confused, even add them together, but the multi-index must be has one level. Not the multi-index. So there was no answer for my question!

Comment: What output do u want exactly?

Comment: Are you looking for `data3.reset_index(level=1) + data4.reset_index(level=1)`?

Comment: yeap, data3.reset_index(level=1) + data4.reset_index(level=1) is the solution. Thanks.